# Удаление элементов в ассоциативном массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
let places = {};
```

В процессе я добавляю в него элементы (ключ => значение).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удаляю элемент через delete places[carriage][0], но вместо него появляется udentified

Как мне можно удалить элемент в определённом ключе, чтобы индексы элементов сместились?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
places[ваш ключ].splice(индекс элемента);
```